# How to access the Event Loop from Node.js code?

Tags: node.js

Is there a native function that can be executed from Node.js code which outputs an array or an object containing the information about what's currently supposed to be in the Event Loop?

Comment: I'd expect the answer to be "no". Why would you want such a thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recently there was [a request](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/1128) to see what is in the event loop, in io.js project. There were two names of functions surfaced, in [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/1128#issuecomment-78409928),

1. `process._getActiveHandles()` gets you handles that are still alive
2. `process._getActiveRequests()` gets you info about active libuv requests.

This the most you can collect from the event loop, I guess.

**Note:** Both of them are undocumented functions and you cannot rely on them in production code.

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for a [`uv_loop`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/loop.html).

There's a `UV_EXTERN void uv_walk(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_walk_cb walk_cb, void* arg);` method you can call to iterate the event loop.

Unfortunately, it's not really exposed to JavaScript - so unless you want to do this for fun (and fork node/io.js) then no.

You can wrap calls to the event loop and monitor those but that's slow and not even close - the actual loop isn't in JS land, only small parts of it - and even parts of that (like the microtask queue) are in C++.

A lot of people think of the event loop like an array - it's actually more like:

[image]

It's a lot easier to hook on `process.nextTick` and the timers than on the poll part mentioned above.

Comment: What is process.maxDepth ??

Comment: @MustafaAgamey we removed that bit maybe 5 years ago IIRC, this answer is 7 and should be read in its spirit of what node does and not as the current state of things