# Purpose behind context.success() and callback()

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

After looking at the AWS Lambda documentation and some stackoverflow questions (especially this one: [Context vs Callback in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906116/context-vs-callback-in-aws-lambda)), I'm still a little confused what the purpose of callback or context.success() is. Also, what was the original reason behind having context.success() back when callback couldn't be used?

I'm asking because I was given a Lambda function that uses both calls, and I don't know why one was chosen over the other at a given point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-4-3-2-runtime-now-available-on-lambda/):

> Context.succeed [is] more than just bookkeeping – [it] cause[s] the
>   request to return after the current task completes **and freeze[s] the
>   process immediately, even if other tasks remain in the Node.js event
>   loop**... [On the other hand,] **the callback waits for all the tasks
>   in the Node.js event loop to complete**, just as it would if you ran
>   the function locally. If you chose to not use the callback parameter
>   in your code, then AWS Lambda implicitly calls it with a return value
>   of null. You can still use the Context methods to terminate the
>   function, but the callback approach of waiting for all tasks to
>   complete is more idiomatic to how Node.js behaves in general.*

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you! So, in general, does a callback only get called at most once for a given thread within the program?

Comment: If I understand the question: yes.