# Issues with AWS Lambda function, invoke error on cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, compiler-errors, aws-lambda, invoke

[The Lambda Functions success VS. Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6i4S.png)

Hey Y'all I've scrubbed the internet to find the issues with my node.js function. The Cloudwatch error is the following. Any insight or suggestions would be massively helpful! The code runs but there are some issues. I do not know where the /var/runtime/CallbackContext.js code is which seems to be the source of the problem.

```
2019-12-11T16:34:24.328Z    0211ab2b-8fea-4391-9cc6-01f5c5244c63    ERROR   Invoke Error    
    "errorType": "Error",         "    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:13:12)",
    "    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:30:51)",
    "    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:57:7)",
    "    at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:69:7)",
    "    at Object.fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16)",
    "    at /var/task/index.js:42:25",
    "    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:444:13)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)",
    "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
]
```

Code: 
Says the issues is line 42.25 which is the context.fail line.

```
 if (error) {
            logFailure(error, failedItems);
            context.fail(JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
            console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
            context.succeed('Success');
        }
```

```html
// v1.1.2
var https = require('https');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var endpoint = 'vpc-esdxl-hx2nubxsqn3wh4hqwmywyy2g6y.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com';

// Set this to true if you want to debug why data isn't making it to 
// your Elasticsearch cluster. This will enable logging of failed items
// to CloudWatch Logs.
var logFailedResponses = false;

exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    // decode input from base64
    var zippedInput = Buffer.from(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');

    // decompress the input
    zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function(error, buffer) {
        if (error) { context.fail(error); return; }

        // parse the input from JSON
        var awslogsData = JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf8'));

        // transform the input to Elasticsearch documents
        var elasticsearchBulkData = transform(awslogsData);

        // skip control messages
        if (!elasticsearchBulkData) {
            console.log('Received a control message');
            context.succeed('Control message handled successfully');
            return;
        }

        // post documents to the Amazon Elasticsearch Service
        post(elasticsearchBulkData, function(error, success, statusCode, failedItems) {
            console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify({ 
                "statusCode": statusCode 
            }));

            if (error) {
                logFailure(error, failedItems);
                context.fail(JSON.stringify(error));
            } else {
                console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
                context.succeed('Success');
            }
        });
    });
};

function transform(payload) {
    if (payload.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
        return null;
    }

    var bulkRequestBody = '';

    payload.logEvents.forEach(function(logEvent) {
        var timestamp = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp);

        // index name format: atg-YYYY.MM.DD
        var indexName = [
            'atg-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
        ].join('.');

        var source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields);
        
        var DXLRegex = /\#DXLORDER\#/;
  //    var LogDatetimeRegex = /(info|Error|Warning|debug)\t(Mon\s|Sun\s|Sat\s|Fri\s|Thu\s|Wed\s|Tue\s)(.*)\t([0-9])/;
        var logtyperegex = /(info|Error|Warning|debug)/;
        var WOrderRegex = /\|((W)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\|/;
        var DXLOrderRegex = /(DXL([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]))\|/;
        var CustEMailRegex = /(DXL([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]))\|\s*((.*)@(.*)(\.com|\.net|\.live|\.gov)\s*)\|/;
        var EMailReferralRegex = /(#DXLORDER#)\|(SFMC),(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)\|(W[0-9]|\|[0-9])/;
        var CouponRegex = /(DXL([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\|(((.*)@(.*(.com|.net|.live|)))\|)(.*)\|)/;
        var atgpathregex = /(\/)(.*)(\t)/;
        var carttotalregex = /(W[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|null)\|(.*)\|([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\|(DXL)/;
        var referralregex = /(#DXLORDER#)\s*\|\s*(.*)\s*,\s*(.*)\s*\|(W[0-9]|\|[0-9])/;
        var ClientIPregex = /(([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9]))\|/;
        var ATGIDRegex = /(20[0-9][0-9])(\t)(.*)(\t)(\/)/;
        var EmailSegmentRegex = /([a-z]w)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])_([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])_([A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z])\|/;
        var usernamesucregex = /(findUser: user )(.*)( found.)/;
        var incorrectpassregex = /(Attempt to log into account )(.*)(with incorrect password)/;
        var nonexistentregex = /(Attempt to log into nonexistent account )(.*)/;
        var badcouponregex = /(noCouponFound: No coupon could be found for the claim code:)( )(.*)(.)/;
        var ccauthamtregex = /(<R20_CC_AUTH_AMT>)(.*)(<\/R20_CC_AUTH_AMT>)/;
        var couponremovedregex = /(in removeCoupon method : Coupon )(.*)( has been expired so removing couon from order )(.*)/;
        var giftdollaramtregex = /(<GIFT_DOL>)( )(.*)(<\/GIFT_DOL.)/;
        var giftredeemdollarregex = /(<GIFTCERT_REDEEM_DOL>)( )(.*)(<\/GIFTCERT_REDEEM_DOL>)/;
        var itemnumregex = /(ITEM_NUM>)(([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] |[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] )(.*)|HEM)((<\/[A-Z][0-9][0-9]_([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])_ITEM_NUM>))/;
        var giftcardpinregex = /(<GIFT_CARD_PIN>)(.*)(<\/GIFT_CARD_PIN>)/;
        var linkshareregex = /(#DXLORDER#)\s*\|\s*(linkshare)\s*,\s*(.*)\s*\|(W[0-9]|\|[0-9])/;
        var giftcardnumregex = /<GIFT_CARD_NUM>(.*)<\/GIFT_CARD_NUM>/;
        var giftcardprocesseddollarregex = /Payment Status in Payment Group,\sso using it.(.*):(.*)/;
        var outofstockregex = /(We're sorry,\s*Item :\s*)(.*)\s([A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(.*)/;
        
        if(outofstockregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var outofstockdesc = outofstockregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
            var outofstockid  = outofstockregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
        } else{
            outofstockdesc = "-";
            outofstockid = "-";
        }
        
        if(giftcardprocesseddollarregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var giftcardprocesseddollar = Number(giftcardprocesseddollarregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2]);
        } else{
            giftcardprocesseddollar = 0;
        }
        
        if(giftcardnumregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var giftcardnum = giftcardnumregex.exec(logEvent.message)[1];
        } else{
            giftcardnum = "-";
        }
        
  //     if(LogDatetimeRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
  //            var datetimelog = Date(LogDatetimeRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[3]);
  //       } else {
  //           datetimelog = "-";
  //       }
        
        if(DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var DXLORDER = "DXLORDER"; 
        } else {
            DXLORDER = "False";
        }
        
        if(giftcardpinregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var giftcardpin = giftcardpinregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
        } else{
            giftcardpin = "-";
        }

        
        if(itemnumregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null ){
            var itemnum = itemnumregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
            var itemdescr = itemnumregex.exec(logEvent.message)[4];
            if(itemdescr == null && itemnumregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2] == "HEM"){
                itemnum = "-";
                itemdescr = "HEM";
            }
        } else {
            itemnum = "-";
            itemdescr ="-";
        }

        
        if(giftredeemdollarregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var giftredeemdollaramt = giftredeemdollarregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
        } else{
            giftredeemdollaramt = "0";
        }

        
        if(giftdollaramtregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var giftdollaramt = giftdollaramtregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3]; 
        } else {
            giftdollaramt = "0";
        }
        
        
        if(couponremovedregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var removedcoupon = couponremovedregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
        } else{
            removedcoupon = "N/A";
        }
        
        if(couponremovedregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var removedcouponorder = couponremovedregex.exec(logEvent.message)[4];
        } else{
            removedcouponorder = "N/A";
        }

        
        if(ccauthamtregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var ccauthamt = ccauthamtregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
        } else{
            ccauthamt = "0";
        }

        
        if(badcouponregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var badcoupon = badcouponregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
        } else{
            badcoupon = "-";
        }

        
        if(nonexistentregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var nonexistent = nonexistentregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
        } else{
            nonexistent = "-";
        }

        
        if(incorrectpassregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var incorrectpass = incorrectpassregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
        } else{
            incorrectpass = "-";
        }

        
        if(usernamesucregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var username = usernamesucregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
        } else{
            username = "-";
        }  

        
        if (EmailSegmentRegex.exec(logEvent.message)!=null){
            var EmailMailing = EmailSegmentRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[1];
            var EmailDate = EmailSegmentRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
            var EmailTime = EmailSegmentRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
            var EmailSegment = EmailSegmentRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[4];
        } else{
            EmailMailing = "-";
            EmailDate = "-";
            EmailTime = "-";
            EmailSegment = "-";
        }
        
        
        if (ATGIDRegex.exec(logEvent.message)!=null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var ATGID = ATGIDRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
        }  else{
            ATGID = "-";
        }
        
        if (ClientIPregex.exec(logEvent.message)!= null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var ClientIP = ClientIPregex.exec(logEvent.message)[1];
        } else{
            ClientIP = "-";
        }
        
        if (referralregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var referralsource = referralregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
            var referral = referralregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
            if (referralregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2].includes("linkshare") == true) {
                referralsource = linkshareregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2];
                referral = linkshareregex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
            }
        } else{
            referralsource = "-";
            referral = "-";
        }
        
        
        if (carttotalregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var carttotal = Number(carttotalregex.exec(logEvent.message)[2]);
        } else {
            carttotal = 0;
        }
        
        
        if (atgpathregex.exec(logEvent.message) != null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var atgpath = atgpathregex.exec(logEvent.message)[0];
        } else {
            atgpath = "-";
        }

        
        
        if (CouponRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var Coupon = CouponRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[8];
            var Coupon1 = Coupon.toUpperCase();
            if(CouponRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[8] == "null"){
                Coupon = "-";
            }
        } else {
            Coupon = "-";
        }
        
        
        if (logtyperegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var logtype = logtyperegex.exec(logEvent.message)[0];
        } else{ 
            logtype = "-";
        }
        
        if (EMailReferralRegex.exec(logEvent.message)!= null){
            var EmailReferral = EMailReferralRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[4];
        } else{
            EmailReferral = "-";
        }
        
        if (CustEMailRegex.exec(logEvent.message)!= null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var CustEMail = CustEMailRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[3];
        } else{
             CustEMail = "-";
        }
        
        if(DXLOrderRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var ATGOrderID = DXLOrderRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[1];
        } else {
            ATGOrderID = "-";
        }
        
        if(WOrderRegex.exec(logEvent.message)!= null && DXLRegex.exec(logEvent.message) != null){
            var WOrder = WOrderRegex.exec(logEvent.message)[1];
        } else{
            WOrder = "-";
        }
        
        source['outofstockdesc'] = outofstockdesc;
        source['outofstockid'] = outofstockid;
        source['giftcardprocesseddollar'] = Number(1*giftcardprocesseddollar);
        source['giftcardnum'] = giftcardnum;
        source['DXLORDER'] = DXLORDER;
        source['giftcardpin'] = giftcardpin;
        source['itemnum'] = itemnum ;
        source['itemdescr'] = itemdescr;
        source['GiftcertRedeemDol'] = "$"+giftredeemdollaramt;
        source['giftdollaramt']=giftdollaramt;
        source['removedcoupon'] = removedcoupon;
        source['removedcouponorder'] = removedcouponorder;
        source['ccauthamt'] = ccauthamt;
        source['badcoupon'] = badcoupon;
        source['nonexistent'] = nonexistent;
        source['incorrectpass'] = incorrectpass;
        source['username'] = username;
        source['EmailMailing'] = EmailMailing;
        source['EmailDate']=EmailDate;
        source['EmailTime'] = EmailTime;
        source['EmailSegment'] = EmailSegment;
        source['ATGID'] = ATGID;
        source['ClientIP'] = ClientIP;
        source['referral'] = referral;
        source['referralsource'] = referralsource;
       //source['carttotal'] = Number(1* carttotal);
        source['carttotaldollar'] = Number(1* carttotal);
        source['atgpath'] = atgpath;
        source['Coupon'] = Coupon1;
        source['logtype'] = logtype;
        source['EMailReferral'] = EmailReferral;
        source['CustomerEMail'] = CustEMail;
        source['ATGOrderID'] = ATGOrderID;
        source['WOrder'] = WOrder; 
   //   source['datetimelog'] = new Date(datetimelog).toISOString();
        source['@id'] = logEvent.id;
        source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString();
        source['@message'] = logEvent.message;
        source['@owner'] = payload.owner;
        source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup;
        source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream;
        

        var action = { "index": {} };
        action.index._index = indexName;
        action.index._type = payload.logGroup;
        action.index._id = logEvent.id;
        
        
        bulkRequestBody += [ 
            JSON.stringify(action), 
            JSON.stringify(source),
        ].join('\n') + '\n';
    });
    return bulkRequestBody;
}

function buildSource(message, extractedFields) {
    if (extractedFields) {
        var source = {};

        for (var key in extractedFields) {
            if (extractedFields.hasOwnProperty(key) && extractedFields[key]) {
                var value = extractedFields[key];

                if (isNumeric(value)) {
                    source[key] = 1 * value;
                    continue;
                }

                jsonSubString = extractJson(value);
                if (jsonSubString !== null) {
                    source['$' + key] = JSON.parse(jsonSubString);
                }

                source[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return source;
    }

    jsonSubString = extractJson(message);
    if (jsonSubString !== null) { 
        return JSON.parse(jsonSubString); 
    }

    return {};
}

function extractJson(message) {
    var jsonStart = message.indexOf('{');
    if (jsonStart < 0) return null;
    var jsonSubString = message.substring(jsonStart);
    return isValidJson(jsonSubString) ? jsonSubString : null;
}

function isValidJson(message) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (e) { return false; }
    return true;
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function post(body, callback) {
    var requestParams = buildRequest(endpoint, body);

    var request = https.request(requestParams, function(response) {
        var responseBody = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            responseBody += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            var info = JSON.parse(responseBody);
            var failedItems;
            var success;
            
            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 299) {
                failedItems = info.items.filter(function(x) {
                    return x.index.status >= 300;
                });

                success = { 
                    "attemptedItems": info.items.length,
                    "successfulItems": info.items.length - failedItems.length,
                    "failedItems": failedItems.length
                };
            }

            var error = response.statusCode !== 200 || info.errors === true ? {
                "statusCode": response.statusCode,
                "responseBody": responseBody
            } : null;

            callback(error, success, response.statusCode, failedItems);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        callback(e);
    });
    request.end(requestParams.body);
}

function buildRequest(endpoint, body) {
    var endpointParts = endpoint.match(/^([^\.]+)\.?([^\.]*)\.?([^\.]*)\.amazonaws\.com$/);
    var region = endpointParts[2];
    var service = endpointParts[3];
    var datetime = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, '');
    var date = datetime.substr(0, 8);
    var kDate = hmac('AWS4' + process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, date);
    var kRegion = hmac(kDate, region);
    var kService = hmac(kRegion, service);
    var kSigning = hmac(kService, 'aws4_request');
    
    var request = {
        host: endpoint,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/_bulk',
        body: body,
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Host': endpoint,
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
            'X-Amz-Security-Token': process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
            'X-Amz-Date': datetime
        }
    };

    var canonicalHeaders = Object.keys(request.headers)
        .sort(function(a, b) { return a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1; })
        .map(function(k) { return k.toLowerCase() + ':' + request.headers[k]; })
        .join('\n');

    var signedHeaders = Object.keys(request.headers)
        .map(function(k) { return k.toLowerCase(); })
        .sort()
        .join(';');

    var canonicalString = [
        request.method,
        request.path, '',
        canonicalHeaders, '',
        signedHeaders,
        hash(request.body, 'hex'),
    ].join('\n');

    var credentialString = [ date, region, service, 'aws4_request' ].join('/');

    var stringToSign = [
        'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        datetime,
        credentialString,
        hash(canonicalString, 'hex')
    ] .join('\n');

    request.headers.Authorization = [
        'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID + '/' + credentialString,
        'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders,
        'Signature=' + hmac(kSigning, stringToSign, 'hex')
    ].join(', ');

    return request;
}

function hmac(key, str, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(str, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}

function hash(str, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(str, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}

function logFailure(error, failedItems) {
    if (logFailedResponses) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));

        if (failedItems && failedItems.length > 0) {
            console.log("Failed Items: " +
                JSON.stringify(failedItems, null, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting a minimal example of your code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Ok will do do now, thanks!

Comment: Where is the code that causes the error (that then causes you to call `context.fail`)? Isn't that what you want to fix?

Comment: Yeah so that is an issue I am coming across, I don't know where the CallbackContext.js code is. I cannot find it in my lambda .js tree.

Comment: CallbackContext is not causing the error. It's catching *your* error. We can't help you debug the cause of errors in your code when you haven't shown us any code (other than the code that later *responds* to the error).

Comment: Apologies, the source code has been added.

Comment: I think you should supplement your `post()` function with a lot of additional `console.log()` statements to determine exactly what is going on, and where the failure is. Right now, I'm assuming that your post to Elasticsearch is being rejected but you aren't showing us any of the diagnostics from that failure. Also, there are Node.js packages available to sign and make requests to Amazon Elasticsearch (e.g. elasticsearch and http-aws-es) so that you don't have to write complex, and possibly buggy, code.

Comment: Ok will look into this thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

I dont see a context.fail() function in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html)

the callback() function takes two arguments: error, response.

Have you tried changing context to callback?:

```
if (error) {
            logFailure(error, failedItems);
            callback(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
            callback(null, 'Success');
        }
```

See [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906116/context-vs-callback-in-aws-lambda)

Comment: You *can* call `context.succeed()` or `context.fail()` as they're still supported, but it's generally discouraged as you should ideally return a promise from an async Lambda handler function.