# Client aborts does not trigger "close" event on Node.js request in Node 16

Tags: node.js, express, http, fetch

I'm building an express app which streams data to the client using res.write(json) which should respect aborts from the fetch in the client.

In Node 14, I was doing this to detect the abort:

```
req.on("close", () => {
  // handle the abort
})
```

However, when upgrading to Node 16, this event no longer fires and through some trial and error, I figured out that we have to do this on the response object instead:

```
res.on("close", () => {
  // handle the abort
})
```

On the client, I'm doing

```
fetch(url, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: jsonParams,
            signal: signal,
          })
```

And that the "close" event on request fires immediately when request payload is available (as opposed to in Node 14).

Is this a breaking http handling change going from Node 14 to Node 16? I haven't found much about this online.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a breaking change. [See this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38924) that describes the following:

> The close event is now emitted when the request has been completed and not when the underlying socket is closed.

Depending on your use cases you can switch to `req.socket` and listed to `close` there which should have behaviors similar to (but not exactly) Node v14.